# How to access a hash value by index stored in variable

Tags: perl, hash

I am working on some code to extract data stored in JSON format from web page. JSON data extracted and decode properly into hash.

The structure of JSON data is very complex, I wrote some assisting code/function which 'traverse' through the hash and helps finds 'index' (location) of a value of interest in the hash.

The 'find' function returns 'index' (location) of the data in the hash which stored in a variable.

I attempt to use this variable (stored 'index') in other operations but so far without any success.

Please see included simple demo snippet code for explanation of the problem.

Thank you,
Polar Bear

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $index;
my $slice;

my $data = decode_json( join '', <DATA> );

printf "TITLE: %-15s TIME: %5s TIMES: %5s FAVORITE: %s\n",
        $data->{playList}[1]{title},
        $data->{playList}[1]{time},
        $data->{playList}[1]{played},
        $data->{playList}[1]{favorite} ? "yes" : "no";

$index = '{playList}[1]';

$slice = $data{$index};     # does not pass 'use strict' compilation error
$slice = $data->{$index};   # empty slice 
$slice = $data->$index;     # Can't call method "{playList}[1]" on unblessed reference at

printf "TITLE: %-15s TIME: %5s TIMES: %5s FAVORITE: %s\n",
        $slice->{title},
        $slice->{time},
        $slice->{played},
        $slice->{favorite} ? "yes" : "no";

__DATA__
{
    "playList": [
      {
        "title": "Song name 1",
        "time": "3:25",
        "played": "240",
        "favorite": "1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Song name 2",
        "time": "4:12",
        "played": "30",
        "favorite": "0"
      },
      {
        "title": "Song name 3",
        "time": "2:56",
        "played": "85",
        "favorite": "0"
      }
    ]
}
```

I expect to access data by utilizing 'index' stored in a variable but I could not find a way to achieve this result. See comments in the code for details.

NOTE: In real life the index looks as following

```
my $index = "{contents}{twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer}{tabs}[0]{tabRenderer}{content}{sectionListRenderer}{contents}[0]{itemSectionRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoRenderer}{title}{accessibility}{accessibilityData}{label}";
```

SOLUTION:

I would like to extend **my '*thank you*'** to Håkon Hægland and lordadmira for offered solution

```
use Data::Diver qw/Dive/; # or Data::DPath, etc

# Capture web page, extract data JSON, convert to hash, assign hash ref to $data
my $data = ...; 

# Find index/location in the hash
#my $index = find($data, $value);

my $index = "{contents}{twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer}{tabs}[0]{tabRenderer}{content}{sectionListRenderer}{contents}[0]{itemSectionRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoRenderer}{title}{accessibility}{accessibilityData}{label}";

$index =~ s/[{\[]//g; # throw away opening brackets

my @index = split /[}\]]/, $index; # split into array on closing brackets

pop @index for 1..8 # 8 levels to back up to

my $slice = Dive( $data, @index ); # extract hash slice of interest

# extract playlist
my $playlist = $slice->{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents};

# go through playlist and extract information of our interest
foreach ( @$playlist ) {
    my $video = $_->{playlistVideoRenderer};
    printf "%s %8s %s\n",
            $video->{videoId},
            $video->{lengthText}{simpleText},
            $video->{title}{simpleText};
}
```

Both of them referred me to `use Data::Dive` with help of this module I can do *back up* few levels from the depth of the hash and extract **slice** of interest.

It was learned that by utilizing this module the index in form of **array** is easier to work with. Due this factor I will *alter* my find function to return an index **array**.

Comment: Hi,

`use strict;` -- is not a solution, it warns that first form of access does refer to %data hash which is not declared ($data is a reference to hash in my case).

Polar Bear

Comment: You can't use perl syntax inside a string that way, without using `eval`. You can save the location as a reference directly by getting rid of `$index` and just saying `$slice = $data->{playList}[1];`. Same with your longer "index".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Data::Diver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver) :

```
use Data::Diver   qw( DiveVal );
use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $data = decode_json( join '', <DATA> );
my $slice = DiveVal( $data, qw( playList 1 ) );
printf "TITLE: %-15s TIME: %5s TIMES: %5s FAVORITE: %s\n",
        $slice->{title},
        $slice->{time},
        $slice->{played},
        $slice->{favorite} ? "yes" : "no";
```

**Output**:

```
TITLE: Song name 2     TIME:  4:12 TIMES:    30 FAVORITE: no
```

Comment: Hello Håkon Hægland,

thanks for your input, I will investigate `use Data::Diver` (it is new to me).

Unfortunately your solution does not **utilize** my `$index` variable.

Please look into my **NOTE** to see what I have to deal with.

JSON structure is quite complicated and to find required **slice** going through the code visually is not easy and takes time.Beyond that the website can change JSON structure any time and the code will require reworking.

In case of my **find** function I need specify only block I am interested in get **index** then extract **slice**.

Thank you

Comment: The code uses `qw( playList 1 )` which seems quite similar to your `$index` variable `'{playList}[1]'`. How do you create `$index`? Maybe you could just as easily create the array `$index = ['playList', 1]`. As the latter can be passed to `DiveVal()`..

Comment: Real index looks like following

`my $index = "{contents}{twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer}{tabs}[0]{tabRenderer}{content}{sectionListRenderer}{contents}[0]{itemSectionRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoRenderer}{title}{accessibility}{accessibilityData}{label}";`

it is more complicated than in the **example** but idea is the same.

Polar Bear

Comment: Yes that is fine. It is no problem, just use `qw( contents twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer tabs 0 ..... )` instead

Comment: I am more interested in **slice** at `my $index = "{contents}{twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer}{tabs}[0]{tabRenderer}{content}{sectionListRenderer}{contents}[0]{itemSectionRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents}` which is an array.-- I know that the **value** is in it. 

Polar Bear

Comment: sorry I did not get your last comment

Comment: So, you suggest I push into an array all **components** of index and feed it into `DiveVal`? I need to try it and see what will **come out** of it. 

Thank you
Polar Bear

Comment: sorry, yes it is not obvious from the post which you could not understand -- I need an access to block where the value was found and not to value itself, I need whole playlist and not just one item in the playlist. With your solution I need to change how I **build** the index (convert it into array) and pop few elements out of array to get into **required level** to extract **slice*.

Polar Bear

Comment: I think it is difficult to discuss these issues in the comments here. I am not sure exactly what you mean without seeing more of your code. You may contact me by email if you like (my email address is in my profile)..

Comment: @Polar Bear, Re "*Unfortunately your solution does not utilize my $index variable.*", Because we're not here to write code for you. If you want to use that format, you'll need to define the language and write a parser for it. This parser will generate the list of keys and indexes Håkon Hægland's code takes as input, so his answer is quite pertinent.

Comment: @Polar Bear, I answered the unanswered question you asked above about why an input format different than the one you requested was used ("*Real index looks like following ...*"). And I also explained how you could get about using that format if you wanted. Sorry that you deem answering your questions (and providing useful additional advice about achieving what you want that wasn't already covered) to be useless. I'll make a point of never doing it again.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you said you had a function that finds the an element in your JSON data structure and returns a "path" to that element, and that your question is about finding a higher-level container of that element.

If this was XML, I'd use an XPath to do both the search and finding the right container. But worry not, someone has devlopped an [XPath-like language for JSON](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), and someone has provide this functionality via Perl module [JSON::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Path).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend **my '*thank you*'** to Håkon Hægland and lordadmira for offered solution

```
use Data::Diver qw/Dive/; # or Data::DPath, etc

my $data = ...;

my $index = "{contents}{twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer}{tabs}[0]{tabRenderer}{content}{sectionListRenderer}{contents}[0]{itemSectionRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoRenderer}{title}{accessibility}{accessibilityData}{label}";

$index =~ s/[{\[]//g;

my @index = split /[}\]]/, $index;

pop @index for 1..8 # 8 levels to back up to

my $slice = Dive( $data, @index );

my $playlist = $slice->{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents};


foreach ( @$playlist ) {
    my $video = $_->{playlistVideoRenderer};
    printf "%s %8s %s\n",
            $video->{videoId},
            $video->{lengthText}{simpleText},
            $video->{title}{simpleText};
}
```

Both of them referred me to `use Data::Dive` with help of this module I can do *back up* few levels from the depth of the hash and extract **slice** of interest.

It was learned that by utilizing this module the index in form of **array** is easier to work with. Due this factor I will *alter* my find function to return an index **array**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is returning all of the keys and elements to find the given element but not the element value itself.  The simplest answer is to return a reference to that located value.

```
... bunch of lookdown code
return \ $this_level->{the_key_I_want}
```

That way the caller can have direct read/write access to the leaf value.

If you want to use the list of keys and elements directly to access a deep value, you will have to do a string eval.  This is NOT recommended unless you 1000% percent trust the data because some joker can name a hash key "; system qw{rm -rf /}".

```
$index = "{contents}{twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer}{tabs}[0]{tabRenderer}{content}{sectionListRenderer}{contents}[0]{itemSectionRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoRenderer}{title}{accessibility}{accessibilityData}{label}"
$value = eval "\$HASH$index";
```

The right way to use a list like that is another lookdown function that takes the list of keys etc and accesses them one by one.

HTH

PS: I slightly misunderstood your original question.  Just write in your code:

`$slice = $data->{playList}[1];`

2nd Edit to actually use $index:

```
use Data::Diver qw/Dive/; # or Data::DPath, etc
my $data = ...;
my $index = "{contents}{twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer}{tabs}[0]{tabRenderer}{content}{sectionListRenderer}{contents}[0]{itemSectionRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoListRenderer}{contents}[0]{playlistVideoRenderer}{title}{accessibility}{accessibilityData}{label}";
my @index = split /[{}[\]]+/, $index;
shift @index;
pop @index for 1..2 # however many levels to back up to
my $slice = Dive( $data, @index );
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed you did not fully understand my question. I have another function (**get**) which returns reference to slice of hash based on known **key**, exactly what you suggested. My original question was **if it is possible to use the index in that form to access data**? I tried different ways and probably **eval** can do it but as you have mentioned it is not safe. `Data::Dumper` when outputs hash, inserts some structure in form `$VAR1->{key1}[0]{key2}{key3}.....[8]{keyn}` which I guess somehow works.

Comment: In my case I know what value I am looking for in **huge hash** but I do not know **location** in the hash yet. I wrote function which "traverse" the hash until it finds the value of interest. The function returns **index** to this value -- now I need go a few **levels up** to extract hash slice. To do so I have to manually analyse returned **index**, remove part of it and then I can extract **hash slice**. But what if tomorrow website changes the structure -- I have to do it manually again and put it in the code (hard coded location).

Comment: To make it easier to comprehend look at YouTube playlist webpage. I know the name of the movie in the playlist but initially I am not aware where in the JSON it is encoded. I run my **find** subroutine and it returns me **index** of the location. Now I have an idea where the **slice** located but how on program level get to the **slice** where playlist is kept? I have other subroutine which can be **fed** with **key** if it is known to get back reference of **hash slice** and it works fine. If tomorrow name of the **key** changes the parameter **key** must be altered in the code again.

Comment: It is not possible to directly use your index string except with eval().
What I would recommend is to rewrite your find function to return a reference to the desired data. Because with any kind of index you produce, you must re-walk the data structure to actually retrieve it which is a waste of time.
Alternatively you can use an XPath style module like Data::DPath or Data::Diver.

Comment: @Polar Bear, Re "*but I do not know location in the hash yet.*", The question you asked is about accessing a value given a known location. If the question is wrong, fix the question by editing it. The comments are not the place for this.

Comment: Please read my question once again - _function 'find' returns an index, how to use this index to access data?_. No any sentence with _access value given a known location_. The script demonstrates that data can be accessed if the location is known in advance, just to confirm that _data_ is there. If the _index_ is _calculated_ I could not find a way to use it (probably with **eval** this behavior can be achieved but it is insecure and should be avoided). For a clarification I added a note with a sample of the index -- what I get in real code.

Comment: You probably did not see that the index was a string? You could write _split each component of 'string index' into array and feed it in form of array to Data::Diver function_ -- then it would make some sense to me. My point is that you did not answered the question asked -- 'how to use the index in this form to access the data', and I have pointed out it to you (and not once).